# Pass typed data from PageModel to Layout Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Am working with ASP.net core Razor pages app.
I have a login screen that I get some data from database and want to store it in ViewData and pass it to Layout page so every page will display this data.
The issue is the Login page doesnt use the Layout page.
For the other pages like Transaction.cshtml  that uses the Layout page I am able to achieve that using the below code except for the Login page

Transaction.cshtml.cs

```
ViewData["AccountBalance"] = accbal.ToString();
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<p>Your Account Balance : @ViewData["AccountBalance"]</p>
```

My question is, how do I pass this ViewData from the Login PageModel that doesnt use the _Layout page to the _Layout page

Comment: What do you mean? If the page does not use the Layout page than what good would it be to pass this information to a Layout page that will never be called?

Comment: Please explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I have other pages that use the Layout page like a master page in ASP.net, but the index page is the login page, so I need information after the user is authenticated in the login page to use in the other pages that use the layout page. Eg. I need the name and email address from the login page to display on the Layout page for the other pages after the authentication is done

Comment: that information is in the Identity database.... you do not need to pass it around between requests.  You can just load it on the controllers and put it in a model.  The way MVC and Razor Pages work(which is just glorified MVC) is that ALL your pages are Html Views and you tie them to a model.

Comment: This I would do it.  All models meant for "authenticated pages" inherit a base model with the properties present when the user is authenticated.  All controllers meant for authenticated sections of your website inherit from a base class that populates that information like email, name, last name etc.... That is how I do it.  I do not use pages because it reminds me of the Failed ASPX... But I am pretty sure you can do something like that with Razor Pages.

Comment: Please can you break it down for me, I am not too good with Razor pages, you have just confused me please :) Thank you

Comment: Hey I have added an answer that breaks down step by step.  I created a little demo app to show you how I would start the project.  Take into account that it might end up a little different in your final implementation.  But I hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 2):

OK there is many ways to do what you want.

I am going to show you one way:

**First** I created a vanilla AspNetCore Web Application that uses **Individual User Accounts** for authentication options.

**Second** create a Base Page Model Class to reuse the properties you need across your private section(The pages that required to be logged in) of the website.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorPagesExample
{
    //this class will be inherited by all your pages that are private
    [Authorize]//this makes it so that you need to log in
    public class CustomBasePage : PageModel //inherit from PageModel
    {
        //this is a custom property shared with all the pages that inherit this class
        public string Email { get; set; }

        //here add more custom properties to share across your website

        //added the HttpContextAccessor to get the username in the constructor
        public CustomBasePage(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) 
        {
            //set the custom properties
            Email = httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            //now that you have the user name you can go to the database
            //and set more custom properties.
        }
    }
}
```

**Third** I added a SecureStuff area to my website like this:

[image]

Notice how inside my SecureStuff/Pages folder I added a _PrivateLayout that will be used by all the "Secure Pages" in the Area.

**Fourth** let's set the Index Page inside the SecureStuff Area to inherit our new base class like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace RazorPagesExample.Areas.SecureStuff.Pages
{
    //notice how we inherit our CustomBasePage
    public class IndexModel : CustomBasePage
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        //notice how we pass the IHttpContextAccessor to the base class by calling the
        //base constructor
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) :base(httpContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Fifth** Let's set the _ViewStart inside my SecureStuff Area to use the new _PrivateLayout like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "_PrivateLayout";
}
```

**Sixth** Set the _PrivateLayout to set the CustomBasePage as model.

This step is crucial!

This is where the "sharing across pages" will happen.  So this you need to get it right.

Add this line of code as the **FIRST LINE** in the _PrivateLayout.cshtml file:

```
@model CustomBasePage
```

**Lastly** In your Startup class Inject the HttpContextAccessor like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //all the stuff here was omitted for brevity
            ......

            //add your razor pages functionality
            services.AddRazorPages();

            //this is is needed to access the user from within the constructor of the base class
            //must be added after the Razor Pages stuff
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }
```

And this is the result:

[image]

**Hooray!!**

Now you can share properties across many Pages in your Secure Stuff Area.
And use these properties inside your _SecureLayout.cshtml

Best of luck!

This is just to get your started. But you need to do some research on your own.